# iOS play audio success on simulator but fail on device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I use audio recorder to record and create file in the document directory, then I play it using audio player. I am able to record it on both simulator and device, but I can't play it on device only.

Notice that 
1. I don't play sound from files, I play from NSData (I store music into database, and retrieve them to play)
2. It works fine on simulator but failed on device.

Here is my code for playing audio

```
- (void)playAudioWithData:(NSData *)data {

    [self stopPlayingAudio];
    [self stopRecordingAudio];


    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];


    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

    [self.audioPlayer play];

}
```

this is the setting for recording:

```
    NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100],AVSampleRateKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];
```

Comment: Did you check whether data is loaded or not? Just log data before play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` try setting the audio session to `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` when recording and then to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` when you want to play back what you just recorded.

I experienced the same thing in my app when recording and playing back audio and this resolved the issue.

Comment: playing the recorded audio is just a dummy example. The playAudioWithData method is supposed to play any audio other than the data just recorded.

Comment: do i need to create session every time I start recording or playing?

Comment: Setting the session every time is what works for me. I've added a small app to Github that demonstrates a way to resolve this. [iOS-Play-And-Record-Demo](https://github.com/maml/iOS-Play-And-Record-Demo)

Comment: it turns out kAudioFormatLinearPCM is not working on device, your code's mpeg works

Comment: OMGPOP - any tips on how you resolved the linear PCM issue?

Comment: Need `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` in `Info.plist`